# Query sheet formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, information-extraction

I have to google sheets. One sheet is a google form response where it says if an item is received and the model number.

The next sheet is an inventory sheet that needs to be checked off. I'm having trouble creating a formula that imports cell info from one sheet to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put sheet name onto singlequotes attach exclamation mark and include range. examples:

```
'Sheet 1'!A1:D5
'Form Responses 1'!A:Z
Sheet5!A5:A10
```

then you can put it into query formula:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:Z; "select A,B,C"; 0)
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(""=IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(D2:D, 'Form Responses 1'!C2:C, 1, 0)), "no", "yes")))
```

[image]

Comment: Can I share my google sheet with you

Comment: @Nancy sure yes

Comment: @Nancy answer and your sheet updated